# HostnameValidation error whenever i try to use with flask-wtf

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have a search in google before but no result, after 3 days stuck I decided I ask for help

```
Information:
WTForms==2.2.1
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
```

Anyone has using HostnameValidation yet. I'm doing validation for input from the form but seem like whenever I try to use this validation method with/without parameter allow_ip= True. It gave me an error like

```
class ServiceForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Service Name',[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=2), validators.Regexp("^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$",message='Service Name must be number and letter only. No space!')])
    type = SelectField('Service Type', choices=[('2','Check Port')])
    host = StringField('IP Host', [ validators.HostnameValidation( allow_ip= True)])
    port = DecimalField('Port Number',[validators.DataRequired(), validators.NumberRange(min=10,max=65535,message='Port must be between 10-65535')])
```

Note: if I changed HostnameValidation to another method, it will work fine but it doesn't give me enough validation I want to do. I want to validate if the field is a valid IP Address or Hostname

Comment: Where is this `HostnameValidation` coming from?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. This method comes from the package of validators. I dunno why in the document haven't document for this method, but it does available in wtforms.
https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/validators.py#L605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason that `HostnameValidation` does not appear in the documentation. From what I can see, it's only used in [URL Validator](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/validators.py#L500) for the host part of the URL. [Its own docstring](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/validators.py#L605) provides the necessary explanation:

> Helper class for checking hostnames for validation.
>
> This is not a validator in and of itself, and as such is not exported.

What you can do is to take the code of that class and [write a custom WTForms validator](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#custom-validators) for your specific case.

Comment: Thank you for the explain and guide me continue ;)

Comment: def check_hostname(form,field):
    check = validators.HostnameValidation(allow_ip=True)
    if (not check(field.data)):
        raise ValidationError('WTF')


Here is the code in anyone has the same problem with mine :D